# iCalendar doesn't send changed times or pick up attendee replies

Tags: php, email, icalendar

I'm attempting to send an iCalendar invite with a RSVP requirement, I've got it sending a properly formatted icalendar, and I can select a response (Yes, No, Maybe), problem is when this is sent, it just goes as an email to the organizer address saying "I clicked 'option'", instead of being picked up as a response.

This is particularly desirable for Outlook which has a list of attendees in it's calendar view and shows the status of these.

I also noticed that when the organizer changes the time or date, this is only a local edit (same if an attendee tries changing the time, a proposal isn't sent to the organizer), I'm uncertain why this is, I'm using the following format:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR\n
PRODID:Microsoft CDO for Microsoft Exchange\n
VERSION:2.0\n
METHOD:REQUEST\n
BEGIN:VEVENT\n
DTSTART:" . $dtstart . "\n
DTEND:" . $dtend . "\n
LOCATION:" . $meeting_location . "\n
SUMMARY:" . $meeting_name . "\n
DESCRIPTION;ENCODING=quoted-printable:" . $meeting_description . "\n
PRIORITY:5\n
ORGANIZER;CN=\"" . $from_name . "\":MAILTO:" . $from_address . "\n
ATTENDEE;ROLE=CHAIR:MAILTO:" . $from_address . "\n
ATTENDEE;RSVP=TRUE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPATION:MAILTO:" . $email . "\n
UID:" . $dtstart . "-" . RAND() . "@domain.tld\n
END:VEVENT\n
END:VCALENDAR
```

I am performing all these actions using PHP.

The `ATTENDEE;ROLE=CHAIR` line was implemented as a test to try and get the organizer changes to be sent to attendees and was not originally apart of the calendar body.